# How to loop through menu items

Tags: vb.net, loops

I'm a starting VB programmer, and I have been trying to loop through menu items, but this error always comes up:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem'
>   to type 'System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem'.

Here is my code

```
Function prop(ByVal objprop)
    For Each mnuitem As MenuItem In ColorsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems
        mnuitem.Checked = False
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Excuse my poor programming, but can somebody help me get this piece of code working? Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes the menu has items and sometimes it has other menus. You should use something like `TypeOf` to see what the type is before you assume it is a MenuItem.

Comment: You should also turn on Option Strict

Answer (score 3):

Set the correct Type for mnuItem.  You are using a System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem instead of the correct type, which is System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.  As you can tell there are different kinds of MenuItems, so you must specify the correct Type.  Also, since this code only returns Nothing it would be better suited as a Sub Routine.

```
Sub prop(ByVal objprop)

    For Each mnuitem As System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem In ColorsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems

        mnuitem.Checked = False

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Full qualification is not required if he has imported the namespace. The point to stress is that the iteration variable was of type MenuItem from which ToolStripMenuItem does not derive. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You're right, I edited to reflect that.  Initially I was thinking that both Types were named MenuItem, but saw otherwise after reading your comment.  Thank you.